# spring-boot A required class was missing while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using eclipse to learn spring boot. I created a simple application but when i run it using `mvn spring-boot:run` I get error. I have a main class which

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("----START----");
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
}
```

This is what my pom looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>Master</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>        
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.576 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T21:40:53-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/265M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project shipWireMaster: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: A required class was missing while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:repackage: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.6/maven-archiver-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.7/maven-shared-utils-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M5/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.8.1/plexus-archiver-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.3.2/plexus-io-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.9/commons-compress-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/2.2/maven-shade-plugin-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/asm/asm-commons/3.3.1/asm-commons-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/asm/asm-tree/3.3.1/asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/org/vafer/jdependency/0.7/jdependency-0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/home/karan/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

How do I resolve this ? I tried cleaning, installing and repackaging but nothing works

Comment: Had a "sighting" of this was overcome once by clearing the ~/.m2/repository dir...

Answer (score 2):

Your pom.xml should be like this. Include "relativePath" in parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Inventory</groupId>
<artifactId>Master</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />      
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And your java main class

```
package com.Inventory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("----START----");
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `spring-boot-starter-web` unless you're building a web app

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue but for commons-logging while re-packaging with springboot starter parent version 2.1.6.

To fix this, I added dependency under plugin section for spring-boot-maven-plugin.

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
             <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
             </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                  <version>1.2</version>
             </dependency>
        </dependencies>
   </plugin>
```

I'd suspected corruption of jar and still feel adding dependency as above is not correct but after several attempts above option worked for me.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and this solved, but dunno what was happening!

Answer (score 0):

In my case parent `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependencies was not compatible. After reducing it solves problem

Comment: Could you explain why you down voted? I have solved my problem by changing version only